# How can I map two timeseries when the time shift between them is changing?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have device sales data and device replacement data, I want to make a rough estimate of a device lifetime by mapping sales data onto replacement data. The assumption is that some spike in sales data would correspond to similar spike in replacements data, then time delta between those two spikes would be the expected device lifetime. First idea was to shift the sales data to the right until correlation between the two graphs is largest possible, the amount by which I shifted the sales graph would be the expected lifetime. But the complication is that the device is improved over time and it's lifetime increases, so delta in graphs increases over time too. How could I approach this problem?

Comment: What technology are you using? Depending on which you use, there are built in graphing abilities to plot series of different lengths/frequencies

Comment: @jros I use python, so I can use any library which has python API. Plotting is not the issue. The issue is to find a shift between two time-series at which they correlate the most  and complication is that this shift is changing over time.